# How does one add the reference to use the SOAP API C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, soap, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I want to make an application that automatically deploys reports made in SSRS to the reporting server. I found that the best way to do this is by using SOAP.

I have been searching on this topic for a little while now and I don't see anyone saying how to add the SOAP API reference to a Visual Studio project.

This page [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155131(v=sql.130).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) seems like it is directed toward the complete beginner with this API (which I am), yet it does not cover step #1 in actually using the API, which would be to add the reference.  What using statement should I use, and/or what is the name and location of the DLL which needs to be specified, in order to start using the API?

Answer (score 0):

I have never done it before until just now but it looks like you just need to add a Service Reference in Visual Studio. Since SQL 2008 R2 the URL looks like this:

```
http://server/reportserver/ReportService2010.asmx?wsdl
```

For more information see this [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154052.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned by [SMM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6490059/smm), you simply have to add a web service reference to your Visual Studio project.
Go to "Project" menu, and click on "Add a service reference...".
Then put your SSRS service address in the window that shows as explained in previous post, and... that's it !

A new folder "Web reference" is now present in your project, with an item inside, representing the reference to the SOAP web service you add.

Let me know if you have some trouble.
Regards,